# NoClassDefFoundError at DirectionalViewPager using

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

Need help of people, who used DirectionalViewPager - library for vertical and horizontal ViewPager implementation. I do everything, as it described at [DirectionalViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager).
But after creation of sample android project get the

```
    10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager$DataSetObserver
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager.setAdapter(DirectionalViewPager.java:164)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at com.example.verticalview.SampleActivity.onCreate(SampleActivity.java:17)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Who had bussiness with equal, please advise something.

Comment: did you check your dependencies? and do a project clean?

Comment: Is directionalviewpager.jar located in libs folder, not in lib?

Comment: yeah, it located in libs folder and I added it as a external jar at libraries. And it also located at dependencies...

Comment: `DataSetObserver` is API class, used by widgets to observe data changes. Widgets register themselves as observers with adapters some time. Looks like your adapter doesn't support it.

Comment: can you tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: have you found a solution ? Facing the same thing

Comment: unfortunately, no. I decided to use HorizontalViewPager in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Besides having this jar in your libs folder also make sure to have it exported within your eclipse project settings. Same window as the add external jar option but another tab (last one I believe)

I wouldn't add it as external jar BTW. in Java a class added twice to the classpath will fail to load. Can't say if that is also true for android.